# JDialog modal=true vs ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, jdialog

Initially I used following code in desktop Swing application. MyDialog is inner class and `frame` is JFrame.

```
private class MyDialog extends JDialog {
    public MyDialog (String title) {
        super(frame, title, true);
        ...
    }
```

Then I have modified this code to support both desktop and applet. So it becomes like this. `owber` is `JFrame` or `JApplet` either.

```
 private class MyDialog extends JDialog {
    public MyDialog (String title) {
        super(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(owner), title, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        ...
    }
```

The issue is that I run code as desktop but **modality behavior is different**. After application is started I click Eclipse in task bar, so application is hidden behind Eclipse. Now in task bar I click the application icon:

1. `JFrame` and `JDialog` are shown immediately on top of Eclipse
2. in taskbar there are two options `JFrame` and `JDialog`, but for both only JDialog appears on top of Eclipse and JFrame does not.

And JDialod does not have following constructor which would be most appropriate to me:

```
JDialog(Window owner, String title, boolean modal)
```

I have tried different fields from `ModalityType` but none of them give same desired result as snippet #1. What is wrong with my approach and why behaviour is different?

**UPD** for mKorbel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WindowForComp {
    private JFrame mainwindow;
    private CustomDialog customDialog;

    private void displayGUI() {
        mainwindow = new JFrame("MyFrame");
        customDialog = new CustomDialog(mainwindow, "Modal Dialog", true);
        mainwindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        JButton mainButton = new JButton("Just a button");
        mainButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        customDialog.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        contentPane.add(mainButton);
        mainwindow.setContentPane(contentPane);
        mainwindow.pack();
        mainwindow.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        mainwindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new WindowForComp().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}


class CustomDialog extends JDialog {
    public CustomDialog(JFrame owner, String title, boolean modal) {
        super(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(owner), title, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        System.out.println(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(owner));

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        JLabel dialogLabel = new JLabel("I am a Label on JDialog.", JLabel.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(dialogLabel);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html), or [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/modality-137604.html), have to carefully with `setModal` & `JOptionPane`, because `JOptionPane` (initalized from parent` == for example exception from `SwingWorker`) locking current container if is there `Modal JDialog`, then `JOptionPane` is behind `modal JDialog`, only `taskmanager` can kill this app

Comment: @mKorbel, seems like `SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(frame);` returns `null`

Comment: hmmm, can you please to post SSCCE, important with JDK version .....

Comment: @mKorbel, it is in update and it prints null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared that `SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(JFrame)` was returning null, so the dialog didn't have a parent.

[SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(JFrame) returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335963/swingutilities-windowforcomponentjframe-returns-null)

Now I use this method instead and it works perfectly (modality):

```
public static Window windowForComponent (Component c) {
    if (c instanceof Window) return (Window)c;
    return SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(c);
}
```

Comment: agreed JComponent must be displyable, then can returns parent