# SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(JFrame) returns null

Tags: java, swing, jframe, swingutilities

`frame` is the only `JFrame` in my Swing app. Since `JFrame` extends `Window` I have believed from description and method name that the code should return the frame itself.

```
SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(frame)
```

> public static Window windowForComponent(Component aComponent)
>
> Return aComponent's window

But it returns `null`, because implementation is like this

```
 public static Window windowForComponent(Component c) {
    return getWindowAncestor(c);
 } 

 public static Window getWindowAncestor(Component c) {
    for(Container p = c.getParent(); p != null; p = p.getParent()) {
        if (p instanceof Window) {
            return (Window)p;
        }
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Do you agree that method implementation is not precise?

**UPD:** I mean that JFrame is passed to the method `windowForComponent`, `JFrame` extends `Window` so there should be additional check like

```
if (c instanceof Window) return (Window)c; //in windowForComponent
```

**UPD2:** So I would have to implement

```
public static Window windowForComponent (Component c) {
    if (c instanceof Window) 
        return (Window)c;

    return SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(c);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the description nor the implementation. What are you expecting to recieve from the method? The native implementation of the window? Anyway, this doesn't seem like a real question, more like something you would like to discuss in a forum...

Comment: You may be confounding _class_ hierarchy with _containment_ hierarchy.

Comment: @asermax, I have added UPD and code for `windowForComponent()`

Comment: @trashgod, might be, can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be confounding *class* hierarchy with *containment* hierarchy. The declaration `JFrame extends Window` represents a subclass / superclass relationship, while `getWindowAncestor()` examines the relationship of two `Container` instances. Note that `JFrame` is a [`top-level container`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) and a subclass of `Window`.

Comment: oh, I think I do understand that. But I don't know why `windowForComponent` is not implemented as my suggestion in UPD2. Though @mKorbel claims that it might JDK-dependant.

Comment: The `null` signifies that "`c` is not contained inside a `Window`; for example, a `javax.swing.Popup` is _very_ platform-dependent. It may help to know what problem you're trying to solve with this exercise.